# Stacked bar chart by groups in C3JS

Tags: c3.js

How can i have a group within a group for a stacked bar chart?

```
I have multiple accounts, which have buys and sells. 

I need to display the buys and sells in a stacked bar chart for each account.
```

I can show just the buys and sell. The tricky bit is showing the buys and sells for each account. any ideas?

Comment: So you need to show: per month (i assume) x multiple stacked bars (one per account) x each bar contains sells and buys?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/tqwxx50a/1

HTML:

```
<div id="chart1"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var months = ['Jan 2016', 'Feb2016'];
var columnData = [
  ['account1buy', 20, 15],
  ['account1sell', 18, 25],
  ['account2buy', 33, 45],
  ['account2sell', 54, 21],
];


var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart1',
  data: {
    columns: columnData,
    type: 'bar',

    groups: [['account1buy', 'account1sell'], ['account2buy', 'account2sell']],
  },

  axis: { x: {
    type: 'category',
    categories: months,
  }},
});
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much. Accepting this as it answers my question. However, is there a way to have the legend by the accounts and/or buy buy and sell only (rather than having buy sell for each account)

Comment: I'm not sure how you can represent the legend with just either accounts only or buy/sell categories only as each permutation would have different colors. In any case, c3.js provides an example for a custom legend area if needed http://c3js.org/samples/legend_custom.html